# Running a Python script in Powershell with Environment Variables set

Tags: python, powershell, environment-variables

I have set an environment variable of `PYTHONPATH`, (system)Path, (user)Path to C:\Users\amwil\Junk.

Inside the 'Junk' dir there is a python file `hello.py` containing one line of code

```
print('hello hello')
```

In PowerShell if I run `python hello.py` and 'no such file or directory' is returned. In ipython, from the same location, I can import hello.

I also tested

```
def hello():
    print('hello hello')
    return
```

(with similar results - Python is recognizing the path but not the system)

`python C:\Users\amwil\Junk\hello.py` works

Error message: 
can't open file 'hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Any ideas as to what is going on?

EDIT: To clarify, I am trying to run a python file from an arbitrary directory (not the working directory). Running python from command line works, as does running python hello.py when in the correct working directory (i.e. Junk).

It would be best to have, say, C:\Users\other as the working directory, and be able to run python hello.py to the command line (where hello is contained in C:\Users\Junk).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen? Doesn't the command `python hello.py` mean "run the `hello.py` that's sitting in the current directory"?

Comment: I was expecting it to run... So there is no way to run a python script from another directory by adding that directory to the path? Thanks for the fast response :)

Comment: In the end I want to use os.system('python hello.py') from within a python script, without having to define the full path of hello.py

Comment: You need to add that directory to `Path` rather than `PYTHONPATH`. But that presumes `python.exe` searches `Path` when it looks about for a file. If this is bothersome, write a short shell script (batch file) that runs whatever command you want.

Comment: I have added that directory to Path (for both user and sytem) and PYTHONPATH
-write a short shell script (batch file) that runs whatever command you want- I'll look into this
This is more to understand what is going on, I thought that running python in powershell searched the Path for the file that is trying to be called, not just the location you are in

Comment: It sounds like you really want to create a file association and append to `PATHEXT`. This is not the right place for this kind of question--you should ask how to do this on superuser.

Comment: I have added .PY to PATHEXT

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right place for your question.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add the current directory to `$env:PATH`, and you definitely don't need to modify `$env:PATHEXT`. As has already been mentioned, `python hello.py` should execute the file `hello.py` from the current working directory as long as `python.exe` is in the PATH. Please check that the current directory actually contains the file and that the filename is what you think it is (`ls; ls | % { '-{0}-' -f $_.name }`). Also add the actual error message to your question.